# Pine seed function in TradingView

Tags: github, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Even after following all below steps, my pinescript is not showing data from my GITHUB repository. I have been trying to use request.seed() fucntion in tradingView for getting Put call ratio data into my charts and make an indicator. I did all necessary steps as per Pine seeds documentation all the way from repository creation, forking that repository, adding .csv files, creating JSON file contains all data files and merged to main repository. but not getting data into tradingview. attaching all detailed snips below.

Data format which is already data checked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFmL7.png)

All data in Forked repository is updated with main repository.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0gVz.png)

No errors in actions tab.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47nXi.png)

I have cheked in main repository also. everything is updated.

Pine script code as follows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOQPl.png)

Please help me. where it went wrong? any help is much appriciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.